# ALV tooltip in a single cell of a row. Possible?

Tags: tooltip, abap, alv

It is possible to put a tooltip on a single cell of my alv? I know that it is possible in a column by a field catalog, but what about single cell?

I have ALV with icon like that, which is called via `cl_gui_alv_gridv`

[image]

I want information about this item in tooltip when I hover mouse over this icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on how to display a symbol with a tooltip is easily available if you google for "site:help.sap.com tooltip icon". Since you seem to be unable to find it, [here is the actual link](http://zevolving.com/2013/10/salv-table-18-icons-and-tooltips/). Make the target field large enough (132 characters is a common size), then use the function `ICON_CREATE`.

If you don't want an icon to appear, you can use `ICON_SPACE`. And since the tooltip is contained in the value of each cell, of course it is possible to have different tooltips for different cells.

Comment: It is possible if i want more than 132 characters ?

Comment: I'd say that even if it was possible, it would not be sensible since tooltips do not wrap at the screen border, as far as I know.

Comment: When i use your method with icon_space No icon appears, but the cell is greatly ellargit, it is possible to avoid this?