# ALV grid tooltip wrapped on several lines

Tags: tooltip, abap, alv

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010425/sap-abap-alv-grid-oo-tooltip-in-a-single-cell/) I was helped to fill a tooltip on a cell in a ALV. I've realized that this tooltip was limited to about 130 characters.

Is there a way to have tooltip in a long text on multiple lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and i think that is impossible !